# Ошибка your user name and password are not defined. ask your database administrator firebird

Tags: c#, winforms, firebird, interbase

Пишу программу на C# winforms, использую FirebirdClient, а так же Firebird 1.5 embedded для подключения к локальной базе.
Вот код который я использовал для подключения к версии Firebird 2.5, где подключение происходило нормально. Но не происходит на версии 1.5

```
FbConnection connecting_firebird = new FbConnection(@"Server=localhost; User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; ServerType=1; ClientLibrary=Resources\firebird1.5\fbclient.dll; CHARSET=NONE; Pooling =false; Database=D:\111.GDB");
connecting_firebird.Open();
```

После чего, мне возвращается ошибка "your user name and password are not defined. ask your database administrator firebird".
Насколько мне известно, embedded сервер не хранит данные логина и пароля, но при этом достаточно было указать стандартные данные, и connect происходил на версии 2.5, но не происходит на версии 1.5

Comment: Вы точно взяли fbclient.dll от embedded, а не от обычного сервера?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Да. Скачивал с официального сайта, именно версию embedded. Позже я переименовал её(где то встречал совет так сделать) с fbembed.dll в fbclient.dll. Но при этом я пробовал и в оригинале оставить название файла, это не дало мне результата в обоих случаях. Архив с firebird имеет название (Firebird-1.5.6.5026-0_embed_win32_pdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решением для меня стало понижение пакета FirebirdClient до самой минимальной версии. Наверняка это не самая крайняя рабочая версия для работы с Firebird 1.5. Нужно будет находить рабочую. Но тему считаю закрыто. Надеюсь кому то пригодиться.